# Append RewriteRule to existing virtual host

Tags: configuration, virtualhost, apache-2.4

My server configuration `example.com.conf` uses a virtual host for `example.com`. It contains a few rewrite rules.

Now I'd like to add another rewrite rule on the same `example.com` domain, without editing the original virtual host configuration file. A new file `example.com-extra.conf` would be fine, as long as it "re-open" the virtual host specified in `example.com.conf`. `.htaccess` files are not an option.

I'm depending on Apache 2.4 and Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I think `Include` might help, but I'm not sure that's the right use for it.

Comment: How might I approve the question (since it was downvoted)?

Comment: The question was likely downvoted as it's very basic and can be answered by a look into the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Include` for this. It's the correct way to chain together several files.